# How to set the selected value for multiple select elements in a single AngularJS context

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I try to create multiple select elements on a AngularJS page in a single context. `names` is a array of available name objects and `cores` is the array with available cores. For each name, I would like to have a drop down with the available cores. This works fine, but I'm not able to pre-select the currently selected core. That one is stored in name.core.

```
<ul>                                                                      
  <li ng-repeat='name in names'>                                        
    {{ name.name }} - {{ name._url }} <span ng-click='delete_name(name)'>[x]</span>    
    <select ng-model='?'                                       
      ng-options='core.id as core.instance for core in cores'           
      ng-change='coreChanged(name, ?)'>                       
      <option value=''>No core assigned</option>                        
    </select>                                                             
  </li>                                                                 
 </ul>
```

I'm quite new to AngularJS, so if another structure or additional controllers, scopes, ... would be more appropriate, I'm open for suggestions.

**Update:**
`ng-model='name.core'` as proposed by haki does not work, probably because name.core is not an instance from the `cores` array. I tried `ng-model='name.core.id'` but that results in every drop down having the same (wrong) selection.

Comment: set `ng-model=name.core` for the `select`

Comment: See my update in the question

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me:

```
<ul>                                                                      
    <li ng-repeat='name in names'>                                        
        {{ name.name }} - {{ name._url }} <span ng-click='delete_name(name)'>[x]</span>    
        <select ng-model='name.core'                                       
        ng-options='core.id as core.instance for core in cores'           
        ng-change='coreChanged(name)'>                       
            <option value=''>No core assigned</option>
        </select>                                                             
    </li>                                                                 
</ul>
```

Double-check on how your view corresponds to your model. My scope variables look like this:

```
.controller('MyController', function($scope){
  $scope.names = [
    { name: 'Marc', url: 'http://www.example.com/one', core: "1"  },
    { name: 'Achim', url: 'http://www.example.com/two', core: "2"  },
    { name: 'Jenny', url: 'http://www.example.com/three', core: "3" }
  ];

  $scope.cores = [
    { id: '1', instance: 'First' },
    { id: '2', instance: 'Second' },
    { id: '3', instance: 'Third' }
  ];

  $scope.coreChanged = function(name){
    console.log(name);
  }
});
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pA8wfQNmZuAHerBVJChC?p=preview)